# Add/change compatibility SimpleMenu/MenuItem from compatibility Fragment

Tags: android, compatibility, android-menu, android-actionbar

I realise this is a specific problem however I feel like others who are dealing with compatibility must have dealt with this.

As the user swipes through various fragments in the ViewPager I would also like the actionBar menu items to change. I am not sure if this is easily doable for the [compatibility actionbar](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html), any direction or help would be extremely appreciated. I am changing the title simply via setTitle() since the ActionBarHelper handles this however i cant find anything for updating the menu items. I tried the following but it fails..

```
public void setMenuDynamically(int resId){
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(resId, menu);
}
```

Looking through the code it seems there should be an easy/obvious way to get a handle to the SimpleMenu and add an item and set its icon.

Thanks in advance ( I am hoping the google boys are reading this as the android developers Google+ suggests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok well please let me know if I suck as describing things or if there just is not much knowledge on this topic. If the first I am really sorry guys. Regardless I seemed to get this to work but am unsure if this is the correct way.

AcitonBarHelper

```
    public void updateMenu(MenuItem item) {
}
```

ActionBarHelperBase (for 2.2 - 3.0 devices )

```
@Override
public void updateMenu(MenuItem item){
    addActionItemCompatFromMenuItem(item);
}
```

And create similar methods for honeycomb and ICS

finally i have a listener for page changing and in that listener i call...

```
public void setMenuDynamically(int resId, String title){
    MenuItem item = menu.add(title);
    item.setIcon(resId);
    getActionBarHelper().updateMenu(item);
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
}
```

I am not sure if the MenuItemCompat is necessary but I included it nonetheless. Everything seems to work great for 2.2 at least. I will most likely have to make changes in the Overrides but I can handle myself from here.